# How is it possible get scroll coordinates of a RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Want to get scroll coordinates of a `RecycleView` like this:

```
int scrollX = recycleView.getScrollX();
```

But it always returns 0, even though view is already scrolled. Why it does not help? How is it possible get the shifted distance of the content?

Comment: you mean horizontal scroll?

Comment: yes, horizontal scroll

Comment: actually getScrollX() is for the View class itself not particular to RecyclerView so yes it will return 0 if not the whole view get scrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
int scrollX = recycleView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnScrollListener to achieve this:

```
private int xScroll = 0;
...
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        xScroll += dx;
    }
 });
```